# Is there a class with the function `(m a -> n b) -> t m a -> t n b`

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

Here's a class, I'm calling `BlahMap`:

```
class BlahMap t where
  blahMap :: (m a -> n b) -> t m a -> t n b
```

This is an instance of `BlahMap`:

```
instance BlahMap (ReaderT r) where
  blahMap f = ReaderT . fmap f . runReaderT
```

Is there an existing class in the Haskell ecosystem that does this? Or alternatively, can I just write a function `blahMap` with appropriate constraints with existing classes in say `mtl` or something similar? Or have I actually invented something new?

Answer (score 7):

The function [`hoist`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#v:hoist) from the class `MFunctor`, package `mmorph` is the answer to my own question.

Comment: To be completely correct, `hoist` has type `(forall a. m a -> n a) -> t m b -> t n b`, which is not exactly what you asked for in the OP. That being said, `hoist` is probably what you're looking for and is a *very* useful function to know, so I like this answer. Just worth noting that the types don't *exactly* line up.